# Can you migrate with Realm in a more focused and linear fashion?

Tags: ios, migration, realm

Is it possible with Realm to do linear, more focused, self-contained migrations, sort of how Rails does it?

For instance, as I currently understand it, if the `Person` class changes twice (so two migrations), when `migration 2` gets added and the final schema changes, `migration 1` will require revision so that it migrates to the final schema.

Is there a way to migrate to an intermediate schema (what the schema used to be when `migration 1` was all there was) in between migrations?

I realize that it would be less efficient, since there would need to be transient tables created and extra work done instead of just migrating to the most recent schema.  However, it's less development time spent modifying old migrations, cognitive overhead, test complexity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many scenarios in which linear migrations in Realm are supported, but the case you've described is not. The reason Realm can perform migrations without having to keep a full history of all schemas, like Core Data does through its xcdatamodeld bundle, is that Realm has access to the schema (on disk) and the target schema (in-memory model classes).

To support the use case you're requesting, you'd have to keep all the previous versions of your schema in your app so that Realm could know which tables to create, at intermediate migration steps. Not only is this more work for you as a Realm user, but it's a design anti-pattern which would undoubtedly lead to less efficient and longer migrations.

I hope this makes sense, and I'm happy to explain this further if you'd like.

For more information, please refer to Realm's migration documentation which covers a lot more: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#migrations

Comment: Do you have a good example of a clean/sane way of maintaining possibly hundreds of migrations?  I'm having a hard time seeing how this could scale without becoming a nightmare to add a migration, which might require modification of dozens/hundreds of old migrations.  Those modifications will also then need to account for many more possible initial states.  Do you have a more real-world example showing how a project's migrations change as it evolves?

Comment: you can still use linear-style migrations with hundreds of versions, but keep some of the intermediate steps in memory rather than in temporary tables/columns.